# Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'chart.js' is not available

Tags: javascript, angularjs, chart.js

I'm trying to recreate some online examples for Angular Charts but am running into an error from the Console.
The error states:

> Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module
>   chartDemo due to: Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate
>   module chart.js due to: Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'chart.js' is
>   not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load
>   it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies
>   as the second argument.

I've loaded the Charts.js before AngularCharts.js as stated in some of the answers to similar problem. May I get some help on why this error persists?

```html
<div ng-app="chartDemo" ng-controller="MainController as mainCtrl">
  <canvas id="doughnut" class="chart chart-doughnut" chart-data="mainCtrl.data" chart-labels="mainCtrl.labels" chart-options="mainCtrl.options">
              </canvas>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.2.2/Chart.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-chart.js/1.0.2/angular-chart.min.js"></script>

<script>
  angular.module('chartDemo', ['chart.js'])
    .config(['ChartJsProvider', function(ChartJsProvider) {
      // Configure all charts
      ChartJsProvider.setOptions({
        //animation: false,
        //responsive: false
      });
    }])
    .controller('MainController', MainController);

  function MainController($scope, $timeout) {
    var vm = this;

    vm.labels = ["Download Sales", "In-Store Sales", "Mail-Order Sales"];
    vm.data = [300, 500, 100];
    vm.options = {
      legend: {
        display: true,
        position: 'bottom'
      },
      cutoutPercentage: 60,
      tooltipEvents: [],
      tooltipCaretSize: 0,
      showTooltips: true,
      onAnimationComplete: function() {
        self.showTooltip(self.segments, true);
      }
    }

  }

  MainController.$inject = ['$scope', '$timeout'];
</script>
```

Comment: Your code has `'chart'` as a module dependency but your error message says `'chart.js'` so which is it?

Comment: I've edited it from chart to chart.js

Comment: And does it work now? If not, what is the latest error message?

Comment: A made your question code into a snippet and it works as expected

Answer (score 0):

load the scripts is this order  before `</body>` tag: 
Angular -> Chart.js -> angular-charts

**You have loaded the script after `</body>` tag**

`<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>`

`<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.2.2/Chart.min.js"></script>`

`<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-chart.js/1.0.2/angular-chart.min.js"></script>`

And then load your script.

Comment: Have modified accordingly, it does not seem to make a difference.

Comment: can you share a jsfiddle link ?